# Avoid parentheses in derived Show instance for recursive type with infix constructor

Tags: haskell

For this custom list type:

```hs
data WithInfixR a = a :> WithInfixR a | Rightmost
  deriving Show
infixr 4 :>
```

The derived `Show` instance (unnecessarily) parenthesizes recursive values:

```hs
ghci> 0 :> 1 :> 2 :> Rightmost
0 :> (1 :> (2 :> Rightmost))
```

Is there a way I can have it not use these redundant parens without rolling my own `Show` instance?

```hs
instance Show a => Show (WithInfixR a) where
  showsPrec p Rightmost = showString "Rightmost"
  showsPrec p as = showParen (p >= 4) (showsWithInfixR as) where
    showsWithInfixR :: forall a. Show a => WithInfixR a -> ShowS
    showsWithInfixR = \case
      a :> as   -> showsPrec 4 a . showString " :> " . showsWithInfixR as 
      Rightmost -> showString "Rightmost"
```

Comment: Doesn't your implementation (did you mean `showsWithPrec` -> `showsPrec`?) print e.g. `Identity Rightmost` as `Identity (Rightmost)`? Anyway, I think this is hard for GHC because `showsPrec` gets information about the precedence context but not associativity context. For `infixl 4 :<; infixr 4 :>; data Shell a = Core | a :> Shell a | Shell a :< a`, we can write `1 :> 2 :> Core` but need `1 :> (Core :< 2)`, even though `:>` and `:<` both have precedence `4`. Minimizing parens is not "mechanical" in the `showsPrec` interface and would require GHC to make a deeper analysis of the data type.